# GROUP BY Causing Issues with SUM()

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I'm trying to run a sales report query.

The total I am receiving buy utilizing `SUM()` is not correct: it seems that the issue could be with my `GROUP BY`.

The query:

```
SELECT salesreport.canprevid,
  storelist.organization,
  SUM(quantity * unitprice * (100 - discount) / 100) AS total, 
  storelist.external_manager,
  storelist.manager
  FROM storelist
  INNER JOIN salesreport
    ON storelist.store_id = salesreport.canprevid
  WHERE salesreport.date >= "2016-01-01"
    AND salesreport.date <= "2016-01-31"
  GROUP BY canprevid
  ORDER BY organization DESC;
```

As expected, I am able to pull:

```
|canprevid|organization|total (for the month of january 2016)| external manager| manager
```

*However*, when I do a grand total of `total`, using `SUM()`, `total` does *not* equal what is the true total amount for the month of, say January 2016.

I'm not sure why some records would be removed or if `GROUP BY` is causing issues with the calculations.

Comment: don't separate you column names by | it is difficult to read instead use comma's (,)

Comment: please post a schema of your tables and sql fiddle with sample data so we can work on your query. If you don't know about sql fiddle just google it.

Comment: INNER JOIN salesreport ON storelist.store_id = salesreport.canprevid might not join all the records if they not mapped properly, try to drop GROUP BY first and check if all `salesreport ` records are there

Comment: @sef4eg  Thank you for your insight! It seems you are on the right track. When i removed the "GROUP BY" it gives me the total closer to the correct amount. If this is the case then perhaps there is a mapping issue as you mentioned. How would we then identify that?

Comment: Not that your `WHERE` clause is wrong, but for the future you might want to consider [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp).

Comment: So what are you trying to get totals for? external_manager, manager, organization, canprevid?

Comment: @sef4eg I am trying to calculate totals for quantity * unitprice - discount. So i have values in 'quantity' column then i have price in dollar amounts in the 'unitprice' column and i also have to apply discount in the 'discount' column. This is why i have the formula SUM(quantity*unitprice*(100-discount)/100) AS total.

Answer (score 1):

Add `storelist.organization` to your `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT salesreport.canprevid,
  storelist.organization,
  SUM(quantity * unitprice * (100 - discount) / 100) AS total, 
  storelist.external_manager,
  storelist.manager
  FROM storelist
  INNER JOIN salesreport
    ON storelist.store_id = salesreport.canprevid 
  WHERE salesreport.date >= "2016-01-01"
    AND salesreport.date <= "2016-01-31"
  GROUP BY salesreport.canprevid, storelist.organization
  ORDER BY storelist.organization DESC;
```